# Need help: 2011 AMC 10 A question #22

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

Question: Each vertex of convex pentagon $ABCDE$ is to be assigned a color. There are $6$ colors to choose from, and the ends of each diagonal must have different colors. How many different colorings are possible?

1) Firstly, I considered three cases: The vertices are painted $3$ different colors, $1$ pair of adjacent vertices are painted the same color, and $2$ pairs of adjacent vertices are painted the same color.

2) Case 1 was where I got stuck. There seems to be $6∗5∗4∗3∗2=6!$ ways to color the vertices, but I am not sure about rotational symmetry impacting this count. This impacts my approach for cases 2 and 3 (which I haven't done yet). Is there 720 cases for case 1?

Comment: You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem (look at the examples for some intuition).

Answer (score 1):

As you said we have 3 cases. For your cases:

1. We pick 3 colours and there are 5 spots for the first pair of colours, which leaves 2 ways we can put the last pair in the remaining 3 places. Moreover there are 5 rotations of the pentagon so we must have 6*5*4*5=600 possibilities for two pairs.
2. For the case when we have one colour pair, then we pick four colours and again we can rotate our pentagon in 5 different ways, so we have (6*5*4*3)*5=1800 possibilities.
3. Finally when all the vertices are painted are different colour, there are 6!=720 ways to assign each vertex a different colour.

Hence we have a total of 720+1800+600=3120 possibilities.

Comment: Isn't case 3 equal to 144? I am not sure if rotational symmetry impacts the answer.

Comment: No rotations are necessary in this case so it's the number of ways to assign a different colour to each vertex. The first vertex can have 6 possibilities, second vertex 5 possibilities, etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, if I understand correctly, the vertices are considered distinguishable.       By the way, I found the solution on AOPS (Artofproblemsolving.com) confusing because I thought that symmetry impacts the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but in case 1 the pairs are indistinguishable. Only the rotations in the given cases impact the answer.

Comment: Do you have any tips for a 10th grader studying for the AMC 10? I find many of the solutions to the complex problems confusing on AoPS. An example is the question #25 on the AMC 10A in 2010: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_24. I was stuck between choices a and b since 480 and 120 (both are divisible by 8 and either seems like the last three digits of 90!).

Comment: Maybe just practice more problems and try to understand the different methods, steps, theorems,... that will make it easier to solve the problem. Maybe this will help https://www.quora.com/The-number-obtained-from-the-last-two-nonzero-digits-of-90-is-equal-to-N-What-is-N.